# Firebase Deployment error. Failure in the execution environment

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

While deploying project to firebase getting following error:

```
Deployment error.
Failure in the execution environment
```

It happens randomly during some functions. While it may fail once for certain functions, on another attempt it might work without error or show error with some different functions.

Please suggest how to get rid of this unpredictable Firebase behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that you are using the right version of [Node.js](https://nodejs.org).**

> Google Cloud Functions only supports v6.11.1

For ease of use different Node.js versions, I recommend using [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

```
nvm install 6.11.1
nvm use 6.11.1
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Then, try to deploy again.

Comment: In the firebase docs it says 6.11.5
´Cloud Functions runs Node v.6.11.5, so we recommend that you develop locally with this version.´
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Answer (score 0):

The same issue started to happen for me recently when running `firebase deploy`.

To work around it, just deploy functions separately:

```
firebase deploy --except functions
firebase deploy --only functions
```

My assumption is that some sort of timeout or limit is hit when deploying everything at once. See the [docs on partial deploys](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#partial_deploys) for more fine-grained options.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did try using `--except` and `--only` as suggested and then deployed all failing functions one at a time.. all of them deployed except one which I have tried again and again but the same error keeps happening again an again. Logs also don't show anything beyond `"Failure in the execution environment"`.

Comment: @laurenzlong can you please help with this?

Comment: I am facing the issue of "Failure in the execution environment" ? how to resolve this.