# Functions Deployement Error Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i am try to post simple code on firebase functions but it is generating error every times

```
errors
functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (53.73 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating function sendNotification...
⚠  functions[sendNotification]: Deployment error.
Error setting up the execution environment for your function. Please 
try again after a few minutes.


 Functions deploy had errors. To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
  firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

code which i am try to deploy is

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);




exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event => {




 const user_id = event.params.user_id;
 const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

 console.log('We have a notification from : ', user_id);

 });
```

facing this error for about 2 days try all answer available on stack and other forums but could able to find any solution anyone can help me in this

Comment: Please contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 0):

You should have your function return something either a value, null or a promise. Other than that I don't see anything wrong. The error you seem to get it's probably a connectivity issue from your side or (weirdly) something on Google's Firebase side.

Also try to update your firebase tools

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Ah and consider this update here for some small changes, since cloud functions are not longer in beta:
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/04/launching-cloud-functions-for-firebase-1-0.html?utm_source=email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=cloud_functions_v1.0

Comment: its means to deploy it properly i have to make large changes in functions

Comment: Could you tell us: what command are you using to deploy? what version of nodeJS do you have on your machine? and update with the whole output you get on your console please? Also check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48060153/5982279

Comment: We need more information, I know you're using the deploy command but are you sending any arguments? like --only functions? what version of nodejs do you have? to see if it is compatible with cloud functions. Have you been able to deploy before? What's the whole output on your console? Someone suggested to contact firebase support but you will still need to provide all this info please...

Comment: i contact to them but nothing happened

Comment: 6.11.1 node js version as on stack someone tell me functions will only work on this version but this also not help me

Comment: out put of terminal is mention in question

Comment: Interesting case! Have you ever been able to deploy before?
What version of the firebase-tools do you have?
Have you tried loggin out and then logging back in?
Also, could you please share us your "firebase.json" and ".firebaserc"? Ah and have you modified your code to return a promise or value?